# How to enable scrollbar in a specific group member added

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog screen on C++ MFC. In this screen, it has an "Add" button wherein it displays its member (up to 8) when it is clicked. I want to implement a scrollbar after member 6 is added. How can I possibly implement as such?

[image: DialogBox]

Comment: Not very easy, but it's doable. You can use a child dialog-box, and create the controls of these groups with this dialog as parent, instead of the main one. The dialog must be created programmatically or as a resource, and have the "control" and "child" properties set - this will make it behaving as a "sub-dialog". As you add groups, the dialog will automatically create scrollbars, if the children lie out of the available area, and you have the scroll-bar styles (properties) set.